# EF6 Transaction Rollback

Tags: .net, entity-framework, transactions, entity-framework-6

We are extending the context object to have a sync functionality with another system.  We are currently doing this in savechanges.  However we realized there is a case when the context will be used in a transaction state using begintransaction with multiple calls to savechanges.  We don't want to sync the data till the full process is done.  We thought of doing it in dispose of the context.

The one issue we have is knowing if the transaction succeed.  If it succeeded then great sync away.  If it was rolled back then we of course don't want to sync.  How do we know the state of the transaction when a context is being disposed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your models that require syncing to implement an interface, iSyncable for example, that promises that you will sync up as soon as the model successfully saves. If you have related tables through navigation properties, save everything and put those into the navigation properties before you make it sync up so that your syncing function has all the objects it needs.

Incidentally, if you need to do any data transforms, this would be where you do it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enlist your operation in Transaction manager to receive transaction related notifications.

[MSDN IEnlistmentTransaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.ienlistmentnotification.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for this.  This is exactly what I need to use for part of it.  I wish I could mark both as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it in the dispose method. Disposal is for cleaning up. Use the following pattern:

```
using (var tran = new TransactionScope())
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
 db.Connection.Open();
 DoWork(db);
 tran.Complete();
}
```

That's all you need to do.

Comment: We are not handling it in the use of the transaction.  We are inside the inherited context object.

Comment: This is exactly what a deconstructor is for: tying up loose ends like closing connections that you have to force open as long as the object exists, finalizing things, and performing tasks you cannot complete until you are finished with the object (in this case, a context). Given his need to do multiple saves and then a final sync, it seems like he wants it to be an automatic process where the consumer doesn't have to call it or is transparent to the end and cannot count on the frequency of saves. An alternative is to extend the model so that it does "whatever" on disposal or scope close.

Comment: Then he should wrap the context. Doing this by inheritance is not what inheritance is for. This breaks substitutability.; Dispose is not supposed to do something that can throw. That's because if the presumably present using/finally block is exited by an exception a new exception would replace the old one.; The solution is really simple once the artificial requirement of doing this by inheritance is given up.

Comment: Aye, true. What about an interface? It's a promise to do something and he needs to promise the syncing at some point.

Comment: MetalPhoenix has it right.  We have figured out a possible solution without handling it in the context.  Will let you know.  However, we would love to know if it is possible still.